# Identify the correct key used by defaults system when changing settings using System Preferences

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, defaults

I would like to identify which key is being changed in which file when a specific checkbox is unchecked in System Preferences (in my case it's System Preferences → Keyboard → Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar, but I'm interested in a general solution that would work not only with checkboxes).

How can I identify this? I am thinking about using a deamon to watch all System Preferences configuration files for changes.